# Retrieving daily & monthly totals from MySQL for use in a chart

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, chart.js

I have a table of 'subscribers' that i want to query and show the results in a chart.

The records in the table all have their own 'created' field, which is a datetime. I wish to display the results of the queries for set time periods, for example I want to display total new subscribers for:

1. The last 7 days, total per day.
2. The last 30 days, total per day.
3. The last 90 days, total per day.
4. The last 12 months, total per month.

My chart data structure isn't really key to my question, I just need a named array, keys being days (or months), and values being the totals.

My question is related to the actual SQL queries. For example, for the days, would I need to perform 1 single query for each day, and get the total for each day using a datatime interval, or is there (as I suspect there is) a much more efficient way of doing this, as obviously I don't want to be doing 90 queries just for the 3 month chart?

Answer (score 1):

You could use function [`TIMESTAMPDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff), for example:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, created, NOW()) AS days, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM subscribers
WHERE created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
GROUP BY days 
ORDER BY days ASC
```

<sup>I have just runed this query on 2 million record table, and it is fast.</sup>

If you wish to explode days in 7, 30, 90 etc. days, simply do it with PHP.